# First view Alert

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

Im having two `textfields` ,

1. profile name
2. profile quote

In my application home screen,I want to show an alert view "Create a Profile" on first launch.And if in next launch profile is exist it should not show the alert view?Can any one help me to code?

Comment: it would be much better to not use an alert view, use a view controller, show it on the first launch, after that allow the user to re-access the view in a 'settings' type view controller, that way they are able to edit it, if a mistake was made typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I needed to do this same thing. I created a singleton class which I used to store NSUserDefaults.

I called it my defaults class.

Defaults.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Defaults : NSObject
{

}
@property(atomic,assign) int numberOfLaunches; 
+(Defaults*) currentDefaults;
+(Defaults*) defs;
```

Defaults.m

```
#import "Defaults.h"
#include "SynthesizeSingleton.h"
@implementation Defaults

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(Defaults)

+(Defaults*) defs
{
return [Defaults currentDefaults];
}

-(int) numberOfLaunches
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"number_of_launches"];
}
-(void) setNumberOfLaunches:(int)numOfLaunch
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:numOfLaunch forKey:@"number_of_launches"];
}
```

--Now just import the defaults class into whichever class you want to use it in.

```
if([Defaults defs].numberOfLaunches < 1)
    {                                                      
            [Defaults defs].numberOfLaunches++;
            //Perform whatever alertView action your wanting to do

              UIAlertView *alertV=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FIrst Launch",NULL) message:NSLocalizedString(@"This is the apps first launch",NULL) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Okay",NULL) otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertV show];
        [alertV release];


   }
```

//If you want to know which button they press, you need to adopt the UIAlertViewDelegate